# redux-saga change root sagas during runtime

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I need to replace the sagas subscriptions for specified actions.

My 1st saga file:

```js
export function* sagaOne() {
    yield [
    // watchers for specifed actions
    ]
}
```

My other saga file:

```js
export function* sagaOther() {
    yield [
    // watchers for other, different actions
    ]
}
```

So I am using `Provider` from `react-redux` to provide the store:

```js
export function getStore() {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const middleware: Middleware[] = [sagaMiddleware];

  let enhancers = applyMiddleware(...middleware);

  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  if (env !== 'production' && env !== 'test') {
    middleware.push(logger);
    enhancers = composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  }

  const store = createStore<IRootState>(reducers, enhancers);
  sagaMiddleware.run(sagaOne);

  return store;
}
```

Then in my index.tsx:

```
//...
const store = getStore();
//...
   <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </ReactRedux.Provider>,
```

In index.tsx I need to change sagas, and its actions watchers depending on some condition. I know I can't replace whole store, `react-redux` does not provide such option.

Is it possible?